# Editable Boolean Columns in ScalaFX TableView

Tags: scala, javafx-2, scalafx

I'm new to ScalaFx and want to create a TableView containing an editable Boolean column with `CheckBox`s (as well as editable String and Int columns with TextFields).
I assume I'll need to use `CheckBoxTableCell`.
I'm using JDK 7u25, ScalaFX 1.0.0-M4/M5 and Scala 2.10.2-final. (I'm not completely certain about the ScalaFX version, but it's definately at least 1.0.0-M5. In any case it's the snapshot Jarek uploaded on August 1 to https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~scalafx. Jarek only compiles for Scala 2.9.x, but I've downloaded his source code and recompiled it.)

I've already managed to get it halfway working based on [Integer Columns in ScalaFX TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477449/integer-columns-in-scalafx-tableview), http://foofighter2146.blogspot.com/2013/06/tutorial-scalafx-slick.html and the scalafx-demo: SimpleTableView. However, I can't use CheckBox's in the TableView and use their values. In stead, I can only get it to work in such a way that I need to type in "true" or "false" to edit the value in the table.

Here's what I have managed to get working thus far:

```
class Person(firstName_ : String, age_ : Int, cool_ : Boolean) {
  val name = new StringProperty(this, "Name", firstName_)
  val age = new IntegerProperty(this, "Age", age_)
  val cool = new ObjectProperty(this, "Cool", cool)
}

object SimpleEditableTableView extends JFXApp {
  val characters = ObservableBuffer[Person](
    new Person("Peggy", 45, false),
    new Person("Rocky", 43, true)
  )

  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    title = "Simple Ediatble Table View"
    scene = new Scene {
      content = new TableView[Person](characters) {
        editable = true
        columns ++= List(
          new TableColumn[Person, String] {
            text = "Name"
            cellValueFactory = {_.value.name}
            cellFactory = _ => new TextFieldTableCell[Person, String] (new DefaultStringConverter())
            onEditCommit = (evt: CellEditEvent[Person, String]) => {
              val person = evt.rowValue
              val newName = evt.newValue
              println("Here we'll typically save the data. New name = "+newName)
            }
            editable = true
            prefWidth = 180
          },
          new TableColumn[Person, Int] {
            text = "Name"
            cellValueFactory = {_.value.age}
            cellFactory = _ => new TextFieldTableCell[Person, Int] (new IntStringConverter())
            onEditCommit = (evt: CellEditEvent[Person, Int]) => {
              val person = evt.rowValue
              val newAge = evt.newAge
              println("Here we'll typically save the data. New age = "+newAge)
            }
            editable = true
            prefWidth = 180
          },
          new TableColumn[Person, Boolean] {
            text = "Cool"
            cellValueFactory = {_.value.cool}
            cellFactory = _ => new TextFieldTableCell[Person, Boolean] (new BooleanStringConverter())
            onEditCommit = (evt: CellEditEvent[Person, Boolean]) => {
              val person = evt.rowValue
              val newCool = evt.newCool
              println("Here we'll typically save the data. New cool = "+newCool)
            }
            editable = true
            prefWidth = 180
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the "Cool" TableColumn, I would like to replace

```
cellFactory = _ => new TextFieldTableCell[Person, Boolean] (new BooleanStringConverter())
```

with

```
val selectedProperty: Int => ObservableValue[Boolean, java.lang.Boolean] = {rowNum: Int => model.characters(rowNum).cool}
cellFactory = column => CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn[Person, Boolean](selectedProperty)
```

in order to get nice CheckBoxes in the TableView (currently, I get TextFields in which I must type out "true" or "false"). However, this gives me the (obvious) error:

```
type mismatch; found : scalafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty[scala.Boolean] required: scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[scala.Boolean,java.lang.Boolean]
```

and if I change

```
val selectedProperty: Int => ObservableValue[Boolean, java.lang.Boolean] = {rowNum: Int => model.characters(rowNum).cool}
```

to val selectedProperty = {rowNum: Int => model.characters(rowNum).cool}

I get one heck of an error message, which basically comes down to the fact that `CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn[Person, Boolean](selectedProperty)` requires `selectedProperty` to be of type `Int => ObservableValue[Boolean, java.lang.Boolean]`, not `Int => ObjectProperty[Boolean]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you should use BooleanProperty, you can find details, including a complete example, in the answer to the same question posted the scalafx-users discussion group
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalafx-users/oedbP9TY5YE/csNi1qhsNuQJ

Comment: By the way ScalaFX is build for Scala 2.9.2, 2.9.3, and 2.10, just follow the link you posted, scroll down a bit
https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~scalafx

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me. I tried using java.lang.Boolean and BooleanProperty, rather than ObjectProperty[Boolean] before, but got stuck on an error in the line `cellValueFactory = {_.value.cool}`. In retrospect it's now obvious I should've used `_.value.cool.delegate`, not `_value.cool`.

Comment: I'd only like to know how to listen for changes inside the table definition, i.e. use coolcolumn.setOnEditCommit rather than that `characters.zipWithIndex.foreach` trick, but I guess listening on the model, rather than the TableColumn is cleaner in any case.